# regex to remove dash from phone numbers

Tags: regex

I have lines like this

```
TEL;TYPE=CELL:343-454-1212
TEL;TYPE=CELL:34345-121212
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
```

I need to remove dashes from them using VSCode.

So far I came with:

Search With : `(TEL;TYPE=CELL:\d*)-(\d*)`

Replace With : `$1$2`

I have to search and replace multiple times (In this case two times) to get the expected output. This is mainly because I do not know how many dashes are there.

Is there any regex which I can use to accomplish, what is being done here in single go?

Comment: Can't you just simply replace dashes (`-`) with nothing?

Comment: If supported, try `(?<=TEL;TYPE=CELL:[\d-]*)-` https://regex101.com/r/kYSGCp/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the number in parenthesis like this so you can restore it, removing the -

```
-([0-9])
```

replace with $1

**Or**
Just repeat this find replace, till they are all removed:

- find: (TEL;TYPE=CELL:[^-]*)-
- replace: $1

Comment: Can you please show the complete search and replace regex.

Comment: the complete search is: -([0-9]). The complete replace is $1

Answer (score 2):

I tried this limited solution.only for 2 or 3 dash.

Search with: `(\d+)-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?`
Replace with: `$1$2$3`

but in the comment that said replace dashes with empty str also a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code search and replace in the current document feature  (not the one to replace in files) supports regexps with variable-width lookbehind patterns, so you can use

```js
(?<=TEL;TYPE=CELL:[\d-]*)-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeuTBJ/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=TEL;TYPE=CELL:[\d-]*)` - a position that is preceded with `TEL;TYPE=CELL:` and then zero or more digits or hyphens
- `-` - a hyphen.

[image]

Comment: Ah, it works. I wasn't sure if that only worked on my machine or globally.